# What is the simplest way to fill a part of my image with a certain color in Processing?

Tags: java, colors, processing, fill

I have to create a drawing of lines with the midpoint algorithm then fill some part of it without the use of built in methods like rect() or fill(). It may be made of any simple shape (triangles, squares, etc.). I made an example drawing of a robot face, where the problem would be to fill one of its eyes. Here that is a rectangle, but it could also be any other simple shape so the rectangle filling algorithm would not be enough.
I read about the flood fill algorithm, but I only managed to cause stackoverflow errors with the recursive method and I can't use queue or stack in Processing.

```
void setup() {
  background(255);
  size(600, 600);
}

float t[][] = {
  {100, 100, 500, 100}, 
  {100, 100, 100, 500}, 
  {100, 500, 500, 500}, 
  {500, 100, 500, 500}, 
  {150, 150, 275, 150}, 
  {325, 150, 450, 150}, 
  {150, 150, 150, 275}, 
  {275, 150, 275, 275}, 
  {325, 150, 325, 275}, 
  {450, 150, 450, 275}, 
  {150, 275, 275, 275}, 
  {325, 275, 450, 275}, 
  {280, 300, 320, 300}, 
  {280, 340, 320, 340}, 
  {280, 300, 280, 340}, 
  {320, 300, 320, 340}, 
  {150, 400, 450, 400}, 
  {150, 450, 450, 450}, 
  {150, 400, 150, 450}, 
  {450, 400, 450, 450}
};
void draw() {
  rect(0, 0, 600, 600);
  for (int i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
    line_(t[i][0], t[i][1], t[i][2], t[i][3]);
  }
}


void line_(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2) {
  float A, B, sx, sy, s, d, i1, i2, t, X, Y;
  X = x2-x1;
  Y = y2-y1;
  A = abs(X);
  B = abs(Y);

  if (X != 0)
  {
    sx = (X<0)?-1:1;
  } else sx = 0;
  if (Y != 0)
  {
    sy = (Y<0)?-1:1;
  } else sy = 0;

  if (A<B)
  {
    s = A;
    A = B;
    B = s;
    t = 1;
  } else t = 0;
  d = 2*B-A;
  i1 = 2*B;
  i2 = 2*A;
  point(x1, y1);
  while ((x1 != x2) || (y1 != y2))
  {
    if (d >= 0)
    {
      x1+=sx;
      y1+=sy;
      d+=(i1-i2);
    } else
    {
      if (t == 1)
      {
        y1+=sy;
      } else
      {
        x1+=sx;
      }
      d+=i1;
    }
    point(x1, y1);
  }
}
```

Comment: The simplest way would be to use [rect()](https://processing.org/reference/rect_.html) to draw rectangles instead of many lines, but it may not be an option depending on what you do. You can decide the color of the rectangle by using the [fill()](https://processing.org/reference/fill_.html) method.

Comment: Not allowed to use

Comment: Thank you for editing the code snippet to include the recursive flood fill attempt you mentioned initially: that is helpful. Is this for a homework assignment ?

Comment: It will be part of a test, but we are allowed to use any resources

Comment: Which course is this out of curiosity ? (I'm asking for multiple reasons: 1. your original question should mention it's for a school assignment/test 2. ideally the resources to complete the test would've been taught and there may be constraints (e.g. use the algorithms taught but not other methods (e.g. can't use `fill()`)). Regarding Stack/Queue you can find these collections in the [`java.util`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/package-summary.html) package (simply `import java.util.Stack;import java.util.Queue;` as needed)....

Comment: ...I'm guessing you already are familiar with the [pseudocode on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill). If it's depth first or breath first graph traversal, there are plenty of good youtube video on the topic. (for example Reducible has a good series: [graph theory intro](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LFKZLXVO-Dg), [DFS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PMMc4VsIacU), [BFS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xlVX7dXLS64) (see flood fill at 5:19)). There are many other videos specifically on flood fill algorithms. It's worth understanding the concepts and the code you plan to use.

Answer (score 2):

@Laancelot is right, you can use `rect()`.

Currently `t` stores coordinates for 5 rectangles grouped in 4 lines each.
By default `rect()` requires `x, y, width, height` arguments.
Alternatively you can use `rectMode(CORNERS)` so the 4 arguments become `x1, y1, x2, y2` which are the coordinates of the top left and bottom right corners of the rectangle.

In your case, you can iterate every 4 `t` entries and use the 1st two coordinates of the 1st array of points, as the top left corner and the last 2 coordinates of the 4th array of points:

```java
void setup() {
  size(600, 600);
  background(255);
  // draw rectangles using top-left and bottom-right corner
  rectMode(CORNERS);
}

float t[][] = {
  {100, 100, 500, 100}, 
  {100, 100, 100, 500}, 
  {100, 500, 500, 500}, 
  {500, 100, 500, 500}, 
  
  {150, 150, 275, 150}, 
  {325, 150, 450, 150}, 
  {150, 150, 150, 275}, 
  {275, 150, 275, 275}, 
  
  {325, 150, 325, 275}, 
  {450, 150, 450, 275}, 
  {150, 275, 275, 275}, 
  {325, 275, 450, 275}, 
  
  {280, 300, 320, 300}, 
  {280, 340, 320, 340}, 
  {280, 300, 280, 340}, 
  {320, 300, 320, 340}, 
  
  {150, 400, 450, 400}, 
  {150, 450, 450, 450}, 
  {150, 400, 150, 450}, 
  {450, 400, 450, 450}
};

void draw() {
  rect(0, 0, 600, 600);
  // iterate every 4 lines  
  for (int i = 0; i < t.length; i += 4) {
    // for demo purposes: map the rectangle index to a shade of gray
    fill(map(i, 0, t.length - 1, 32, 192));
    // render the rectangle (using every 1st and 4th pair of points of each rectangle
    rect(t[i][0], t[i][1], t[i + 3][2], t[i + 3][3]);
  }
}
```

You're asking for the simplest way: you can avoid the redundant data and simply use 4 coordinates for each rectangle:

```java
void setup() {
  size(600, 600);
  background(255);
  rectMode(CORNERS);
}

float t[][] = {
  {100, 100, 500, 500}, 
  
  {150, 150, 275, 275}, 
  
  {325, 150, 450, 275}, 
  
  {280, 300, 320, 340}, 
  
  {150, 400, 450, 450}
};

void draw() {
  rect(0, 0, 600, 600);
  
  for (int i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
    fill(map(i, 0, t.length - 1, 32, 192));
    rect(t[i][0], t[i][1], t[i][2], t[i][3]);
  }
}
```

Of course can also structure your data in `x, y, width, height` format:

```java
void setup() {
  size(600, 600);
  background(255);
}
// rectangle x, y, width, height data
float t[][] = {
  {100, 100, 400, 400}, 
  
  {150, 150, 125, 125}, 
  
  {325, 150, 125, 125}, 
  
  {280, 300, 40, 40}, 
  
  {150, 400, 300, 50}
};

void draw() {
  rect(0, 0, 600, 600);
  
  for (int i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
    fill(map(i, 0, t.length - 1, 32, 192));
    rect(t[i][0], t[i][1], t[i][2], t[i][3]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as you cannot use fill, here's another way to accomplish what you're doing. But heads up, it's quick and dirty work.

The idea here is simple: as you're using very simple lines on a uniquely colored background, I wrote a method which lets you target a single pixel and flood it (and it's same-color surroundings) with a color of your choice by editing the sketch's pixel array directly. I deliberately made no change to the way you draw the base image because I am working on the assumption that it is imposed.

I commented the code for an easy reading.

```
void setup() {
  background(255);
  size(600, 600);
}

float t[][] = {
  {100, 100, 500, 100}, 
  {100, 100, 100, 500}, 
  {100, 500, 500, 500}, 
  {500, 100, 500, 500}, 
  {150, 150, 275, 150}, 
  {325, 150, 450, 150}, 
  {150, 150, 150, 275}, 
  {275, 150, 275, 275}, 
  {325, 150, 325, 275}, 
  {450, 150, 450, 275}, 
  {150, 275, 275, 275}, 
  {325, 275, 450, 275}, 
  {280, 300, 320, 300}, 
  {280, 340, 320, 340}, 
  {280, 300, 280, 340}, 
  {320, 300, 320, 340}, 
  {150, 400, 450, 400}, 
  {150, 450, 450, 450}, 
  {150, 400, 150, 450}, 
  {450, 400, 450, 450}
};

void draw() {
  rect(0, 0, 600, 600);

  for (int i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
    line(t[i][0], t[i][1], t[i][2], t[i][3]);
  }
  
  // here I am targeting a pixel in the robot's left eye to paint this area red
  floodFill(200, 200, color(200, 0, 0));
}

// you can start the flooding with simple XY coordinates
void floodFill(int x, int y, color newColor) {  
  // loading the pixels array
  loadPixels();

  // starting the recursion: the target pixel's color will be overwritten within bounds
  // I first need to transform the XY coordinates into the array's index
  // as it's a 1 dimension array, it means that it's numbered from 0 to (width * height), so as an example
  // if the sketch is 600 pixels wide, index 0 is top left, index 600 is first pixel of the second row, etc.
  // so the target pixel's index will be calculated as this: x + (y * width)
  int targetIndex = x + (y*width);
  floodRecursion(targetIndex, pixels[targetIndex], newColor);

  // updating the pixel array with the new values
  updatePixels();
}

void floodRecursion(int index, color targetColor, color newColor) {
  // making sure that the point is inside the sketch's bounds... to avoid out-of-bounds errors
  // and also that the current cell's color is the target color to avoid overwritting everything
  if (index < width*height && index >= 0 && pixels[index] == targetColor) {
    // changing the color in the pixels array
    pixels[index] = newColor;

    // calling this method on adjacent pixels (going recursive! I love recursion)
    // first, left and right pixels:
    if (index % width != 0) {
      // this if check makes sure that we dont go from the leftmost pixel to the rightmost pixel accidentally
      floodRecursion(index+1, targetColor, newColor);
    }
    if (index-1 % width != 0) {
      // same than the last check, but the other way around
      floodRecursion(index-1, targetColor, newColor);
    }
    // now, up and down. As this is a 1-dimentional array, it means we must add a whole row's number of pixels to get to the next line
    // we don't have to worry about going too high or too low since it'll be out of the array's bounds (and we already checked for that)
    floodRecursion(index - width, targetColor, newColor);
    floodRecursion(index + width, targetColor, newColor);
  }
}
```

Hope this helps. Have fun!